Jquery files not loaded correctly after integrating with Okta OIDC an ASP.NET MVC app on .NET 4.6.2
I am working on an ASP.NET MVC app running on .NET 4.6.2. It had forms-based authentication (checking username and password against values from database), but now I removed this functionality and added Okta OIDC instead. I am using Okta.AspNet library for this integration and I have this Startup.cs file added as per documentation:
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(App.UI.Startup))]

namespace App.UI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
            });
    
            app.UseOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions()
            {
                OktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OktaDomain"],
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientSecret"],
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"],
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
                GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
                Scope = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "email", "address" },
            });
        }
    }
}

Everything works ok when debugging in Visual Studio or when deployed to IIS on my local machine, but I have some problems since I deployed to IIS in an Azure VM, with jQuery files not being loaded anymore. If I redeploy the old version, everything works ok, so I don't think I have broken some IIS permissions.
The jQuery files are added in the BundleConfig.cs:
public class BundleConfig
{
     // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
     public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
     {
         #region jQuery and plugins

         bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jquery").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
         bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jqueryui").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

         bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jqueryval").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                     "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
    }
}

In the browser console I can see I get a 302 instead of 200 (as on local machine)
In the header it redirects to the error page instead.
I tried to look into IIS logs, but it did not help too much. I rechecked IIS permission, tried to use another Okta app integration to be sure on configurations added, even made some changes to web.config as suggested on internet, but still does not work.
Here is something I tried in web.config, but nothing changed:
<location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

Any ideas?

You can try accessing the jQuery files directly via the browser by navigating to the full URL to see if they load or if an error is returned.

Sorry for my late reply, but this was put on hold. But I am back to this. So here is the interesting thing. If I copy the link from where it tries to load the jquery files and open in another tab (but same browser) I get also redirected to the error page. If I open it incognito, I can see the content of the jquery file loaded. And this behavior does not apply to all .js files from Script folder, just to some.
